# GCC --disable-nls, --enable-languages, --without-headers Unrecognized

Tags: 14.04, bash, gcc, make, cross-compilation

I'm trying to make a `bash` script that will install a gcc cross-compiler for i686-elf on a Debian computer, but I keep getting the same error:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-nls, --enable-languages, --without-headers
make: *** No rule to make target 'all-gcc'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'all-target-libgcc'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'install-gcc'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'install-target-libgcc'.  Stop.
```

Does anyone have any idea why these options aren't recognized? I've installed this version before without this problem.

In case it helps, here's my script:

```
####################################
echo Stage 1 - Building Dependencies
####################################

# make a working directory
cd $HOME/Documents
rm -rf Cross
mkdir Cross
cd Cross

# install or update all apt-get dependencies
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gcc                   # not cross
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install bison
sudo apt-get install flex
sudo apt-get install gawk
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg
sudo apt-get install mpc
sudo apt-get install texinfo               # optional
sudo apt-get install libcloog-isl-dev      # optional
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install glibc-devel
sudo apt-get -y install gcc-multilib libc6-i386

# download and unpack necessary files
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/binutils-2.25.1.tar.gz
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-5.3.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/mpc/mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz
for f in *.tar*; do tar xf $f; done
mv mpc-1.0.3 gcc-5.2.0

# create installation directory
sudo mkdir -p /opt/cross
sudo chown user /opt/cross
export PREFIX=/opt/cross
export TARGET=i686-elf
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"

################################
echo Stage 2 - Building Compiler
################################

# install binutils
mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils
../binutils-2.25.1/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror
make
make install
cd ..

# install gcc
mkdir build-gcc
cd build-gcc
../gcc-5.2.0/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
make all-gcc
make all-target-libgcc
make install-gcc
make install-target-libgcc
```

Comment: I can see one thing, you need to have an extraction for the gzip file with your tar command.  It would be `tar zxf $f` or `tar zvxf $f`

Comment: @Terrance it seems to extract fine, but I will add that in anyway.

Comment: I guess old habits are still with me.  I have always done the `z` for gzip files.  Anyway, I could duplicate your problem with the gcc-5.2.0.  But when I downloaded gcc-5.3.0, I was able to make it work.

Comment: Should I use the same version of binutils and mpc?

Comment: Yes, those work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the finished file (`setup-gcc.sh`):

```
####################################
echo Stage 1 - Building Dependencies
####################################

# make a working directory
cd $HOME/Documents
rm -rf Cross
mkdir Cross
cd Cross

# install or update all apt-get dependencies
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gcc                   # not cross
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install bison
sudo apt-get install flex
sudo apt-get install gawk
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg
sudo apt-get install mpc
sudo apt-get install texinfo               # optional
sudo apt-get install libcloog-isl-dev      # optional
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install glibc-devel
sudo apt-get -y install gcc-multilib libc6-i386

# download and unpack necessary files
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/binutils-2.25.1.tar.gz
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-5.3.0/gcc-5.3.0.tar.gz
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/mpc/mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz
for f in *.tar*; do tar zvxf $f; done

# create installation directory
mkdir Install
export PREFIX="$HOME/Documents/Cross/Install"
export TARGET=i686-elf
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"

################################
echo Stage 2 - Building Compiler
################################

# install mpc
mkdir build-mpc
cd build-mpc
../mpc-1.0.3/configure --prefix="$PREFIX"
make -j2
make -j2 check
make -j2 install
cd ..

# install binutils
mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils
../binutils-2.25.1/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror
make -j2
make -j2 install
cd ..

# install gcc
mkdir build-gcc
cd build-gcc
../gcc-5.3.0/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers --with-mpc="$PREFIX"
make -j2 all-gcc
make -j2 all-target-libgcc
make -j2 install-gcc
make -j2 install-target-libgcc
```

Thanks to @Terrance for helping work out the problems. From there, I worked out the rest, did a few major performance improvements, and made it so it should work on all systems.

Once you have it installed, you can run it with:

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/Documents/Cross/Install"
export TARGET=i686-elf
$PREFIX/bin/$TARGET-gcc --version
```

Unfortunately, doing this inside of an alias or bash script doesn't seem to properly launch it, so, unless this gets fixed, you might have to just store the script in a text file and copy-paste it into terminal every time you reboot.

To uninstall your cross-compiler, simply delete the `$HOME/Documents/Cross directory.`

As a final note, changing the installation directory or target is as easy as changing the value of `$PREFIX` or `$TARGET`, but I wouldn't recommend it, because you may run into other unexpected problems.

Comment: Can you not add those last lines to your `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: @LucasRamage you can!